# R Problems to transform a number as date

Tags: r

I'm trying to convert a column of a data frame (DA$Date), but I'm not getting it.

In my column has numbers like 1012010 corresponding to 1 January 2010.
I'm using the command

> dates <- as.Date (DA $ Date, format = "% d% m% y")

but the result leaves

> dates[1]
>
> [1] "10/12/2001"

That does not match the correct date.

Already used the command

> dates2 <- as.POSIXct (as.numeric (as.character (DA $ data)), origin = "2010-01-01")

but not got success.

Exemple of column Date

> 1012010
> 1012010
> 1012010
> 1012010
> 1012010
> 1012010
> 1012010
> 1012010
> 1012010
> 1012010
> 2012010
> 2012010
> 2012010
> 2012010
> 2012010
> 2012010
> 2012010
> 2012010
> 2012010
> 2012010
> 3012010
> 3012010
> 3012010
> 3012010
> 3012010
> 3012010
> 3012010
> 3012010
> 3012010
> 3012010
> 3012010
> 3012010
> 3012010
> 2012010
> 3012010
> 4012010
> 4012010
> 4012010
> 4012010
> 4012010
> 4012010
> 4012010
> 4012010
> 4012010
> 4012010
> 4012010
> 4012010
> 4012010
> 4012010
> 4012010
> 4012010
> 4012010
> 4012010
> 4012010
> 4012010
> 4012010
> 4012010
> 4012010
> 4012010
> 4012010
> 4012010
> 5012010
> 5012010
> 5012010
> 5012010
> 5012010
> 5012010
> 5012010
> 5012010
> 5012010
> 5012010
> 5012010
> 3012010
> 6012010
> 6012010
> 2012010
> 6012010
> 2012010
> 6012010
> 6012010
> 6012010
> 6012010
> 6012010
> 6012010
> 6012010
> 6012010
> 6012010
> 6012010
> 6012010
> 6012010
> 6012010
> 6012010
> 7012010
> 7012010
> 7012010
> 7012010
> 7012010
> 7012010
> 7012010

Comment: Try with `dmy(1012010)` from `library(lubridate)`

Comment: please show us some some more rows from your column to help specify the date format. Your example is ambiguous as it could be day/month or month/day. given your code, it looks like the months have leading zeroes?

Comment: do you have variable number of digits in your dataset

Comment: In your data, is the day always 2 digits long? Is the month? For example, would February 9, 2010 be written as "292010", or "02092010"? The second case would be much easier to handle.

Comment: I added a column sample

Comment: What does that `6012010` means?  - 6 January 2010?   and what will be 16 Jan 2010 in your dataset also what will be 16 Dec 2010

Comment: Based on the way your data is ordered, it seems to me that 1012010 is 1-Jan-2010 rather than 10-Jan-2010 because there is no 60-Jan-2010.  It would be 6-Jan-2010 and it is ordered in that daywise way.  I that case the `dmy(1012010)` is the way to go.

Comment: I used the command dmy (1012010), and was ok for a part, but then returned error > Warning message: 11822 failed to parse. My column has 43432 elements. For 16 Jan 2010 was 16012010 and 1st Jan 2010 1012010

Comment: @Eraldo You said earlier that `1012010` is for 10 - Jan 2010

Comment: Oh sorry about that, I just change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this by padding 0 at the front and then use `as.Date` with `format = "%d%m%Y"`

```
as.Date(sprintf("%08d", v1), "%d%m%Y")
#[1] "2010-01-01" "2010-01-06" "2010-01-16" "2010-12-01" "2010-12-15"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(1012010, 6012010, 16012010, 1122010, 15122010)
```